# Javascript bug variable

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this problem with my jQuery / JavaScript.
I have 1 div on the left side and 3 divs on the right side.

Now when I click on a div it should move that one to the left and move the existing one to the right.

This works fine.

But for some reason the first and third time I click on an item on the right it only moves to the left.
And not move the existing one to the right. I get no errors.

Also if I keep clicking after everything works just fine how it should. How can I fix this?

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {
  var rightContainer = document.getElementById('rightContainer');
  var leftDiv = document.getElementById('leftDiv');

  jQuery("#info1").click(function() {
    leftDiv.firstChild;
    if (leftDiv !== this) {
      if (leftDiv !== null) {
        rightContainer.appendChild(leftDiv.firstChild);
      }

      // Move the clicked div to the left
      leftDiv.appendChild(this);
    }
  });

  jQuery("#info2").click(function() {
    leftDiv.firstChild;
    if (leftDiv !== this) {
      if (leftDiv !== null) {
        rightContainer.appendChild(leftDiv.firstChild);
      }

      // Move the clicked div to the left
      leftDiv.appendChild(this);
    }
  });
  jQuery("#info3").click(function() {
    leftDiv.firstChild;
    if (leftDiv !== this) {
      if (leftDiv !== null) {
        rightContainer.appendChild(leftDiv.firstChild);
      }

      // Move the clicked div to the left
      leftDiv.appendChild(this);
    }
  });
  jQuery("#info4").click(function() {
    leftDiv.firstChild;
    if (leftDiv !== this) {
      if (leftDiv !== null) {
        rightContainer.appendChild(leftDiv.firstChild);
      }

      // Move the clicked div to the left
      leftDiv.appendChild(this);
    }
  });
});
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  display: flex;
  height: 100vh;
}

#container {
  display: flex;
  width: 50%;
}

#leftDiv {
  flex: 1;
}

#rightContainer {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 50%;
}

.clickableDiv {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: #f0f0f0;
  transition: background-color 0.3s ease;
}


/* Style for better visibility */

.clickableDiv:hover {
  background-color: #e0e0e0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container">
  <div id="leftDiv">
    <div class="clickableDiv" id="info1">Div 1</div>
  </div>
  <div id="rightContainer">
    <div class="clickableDiv" id="info2">Div 2</div>
    <div class="clickableDiv" id="info3">Div 3</div>
    <div class="clickableDiv" id="info4">Div 4</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

only 1 item on the left, not multiple.

Comment: Please see [ask], then revise your title to ask a clear, specific question.

Comment: Your issue is that `leftDiv.firstChild` *includes* the whitespace.  You need to either filter out the whitespace or generate your HTML without whitespace.   Or just use [tag:jquery] throughout which ignores whitespace elements.

Comment: Protip: You should not have separate nearly identical functions for each of your IDs. Use _one_ function based on a shared class and pass in the event or element.

Comment: Why is there a random `leftDiv.firstChild;` statement?

Comment: hmm. aren't both of those if statements, in all 4 event handlers, effectively useless because they're always true? Why do you check so heavily for the leftDiv to exist and not the rightContainer? Why are these two divs named so differently if they seem to serve similar purposes? All four of these event handlers can be replaced with a single event handler using the clickableDiv classname or a new common classname.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The jQuery snippet below should be what you're looking for:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    function swapElements() {
        var clickedIndex = $(this).index();
        var container = $(this).parent();
        var otherContainer = $('.container').not(container);
        var firstOtherChild = otherContainer.find('.child:first');
        var clonedChild = $(this).clone();

        firstOtherChild.replaceWith(clonedChild);
        $(this).replaceWith(firstOtherChild);

        // Re-attach click event again to the new elements
        $('.container .child').off('click').on('click', swapElements);
    }

    // Initial click event setup
    $('.container .child').on('click', swapElements);
});
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  display: flex;
  height: 100vh;
}

#container {
  display: flex;
  width: 50%;
}

#leftContainer,
#rightContainer {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 50%;
}

.clickableDiv {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: #f0f0f0;
  transition: background-color 0.3s ease;
}


/* Style for better visibility */

.clickableDiv:hover {
  background-color: #e0e0e0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container">
  <div id="leftContainer" class="container">
    <div class="clickableDiv child" id="info1">Div 1</div>
  </div>
  <div id="rightContainer" class="container">
    <div class="clickableDiv child" id="info2">Div 2</div>
    <div class="clickableDiv child" id="info3">Div 3</div>
    <div class="clickableDiv child" id="info4">Div 4</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The snippet is cloning the elements and then replacing them with the clone of the alternate element. You just have to make sure you add the click event to the new clones and you're good to go.

This method removes the need for repeated functions and allows you to adjust how many child elements are in each container.

(I also cleaned up your CSS and HTML a bit)